# Is there a way to render a string like 'Hello, %(name)s' % {'name':'Felix'} in Java?

Tags: java, python, render

In Python we can do this easily:

```
data = {'name':'Felix'}
s = 'Hello, %(name)s' % data
s
'Hello, Felix'
```

Is there a similar way in Java to implement the same thing?

PS:
Sorry for the unclear question. the use case is : we have a map which stores the key-values, the Template only need to specify a key in the map, then the value of the key will be in the place where the key is in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under this use case, you need a template engine like velocity or freemarker to use a Map-like data structure to render a string template, there is no builtin module in java to do that. like this(with velocity):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Context context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("appid", "9876543d1");
    context.put("ds", "2013-09-11");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    String template = "APPID is ${appid} and DS is ${ds}";
    Velocity.evaluate(context, sw, "velocity", template);
    System.out.println(sw.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you can use [`String#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) for this:

```
String name = "Felix";
String s = String.format("Hello, %s", name);
System.out.println(s);
```

This will print

```
Hello, Felix
```

More info about how to use the formatting of `String#format` can be found on [`java.util.Formatter` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You want [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method.

```
String data  = "Hello, %s";
String updated = String.format(data, "Felix");
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>If you want to replace only Strings with Strings then code from second part of my answer will be better</sub>

Java [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class doesn't support `%(key)s` form, but instead you can use `%index$s` where index is counted from 1 like in this example

```
System.out.format("%3$s, %2$s, %1s", "a", "b", "c");
// indexes                            1    2    3
```

output:

```
c, b, a
```

So all you need to do is create some array that will contain values used in pattern and change key names to its corresponding indexes (increased by 1 since first index used by Formatter is written as `1$` not as `0$` like we would expect for arrays indexes).

Here is example of method that will do it for you

```
// I made this Pattern static and put it outside of method to compile it only once,
// also it will match every (xxx) that has % before it, but wont include %
static Pattern formatPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=%)\\(([^)]+)\\)");

public static String format(String pattern, Map<String, ?> map) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    List<Object> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();

    Matcher m = formatPattern.matcher(pattern);

    while (m.find()) {

        String key = m.group(1);//group 1 contains part inside parenthesis

        Object value = map.get(key);
        // If map doesn't contain key, value will be null.
        // If you want to react somehow to null value like throw some
        // Exception
        // now is the good time.

        if (valuesList.contains(value)) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, (valuesList.indexOf(value) + 1) + "\\$");
        } else {
            valuesList.add(value);
            m.appendReplacement(sb, valuesList.size() + "\\$");
        }
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    return String.format(sb.toString(), valuesList.toArray());
}
```

usage

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("name", "Felix");
map.put("age", 70);

String myPattern = 
        "Hi %(emptyKey)s! My name is %(name)s %(name)s and I am %(age)s years old";
System.out.println(format(myPattern, map));
```

output:

```
Hi null! My name is Felix Felix and I am 70 years old
```

As you can see you can use same key few times (in our case `name`) and if your map wont contain key used in your String pattern (like `emptyKey`) it will be replaced with `null`.

---

Above version was meant to let you set type of data like `s` `d` and so on, but if your data will always be replaced with Strings, then you can skip `String.format(sb.toString(), valuesList.toArray())` and replace all your keys with values earlier.

Here is simpler version that will accept only map with `<String,String>` key-value relationship.

```
static Pattern stringsPattern = Pattern.compile("%\\(([^)]+)\\)s\\b");

public static String formatStrings(String pattern, Map<String, String> map) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = stringsPattern.matcher(pattern);

    while (m.find()) {
        // we can't use null as replacement so we need to convert it to String
        // first. We can do it with String.valueOf method
        m.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(map.get(m.group(1))));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more advanced techniques like i18n support, you can use the advanced Message Format features

ex: 
in langage properties files you add the property 'template' wich is your message

```
template = At {2,time,short} on {2,date,long}, \
    we detected {1,number,integer} spaceships on \
    the planet {0}.
```

then you can format your valriables pass the arguments in an array:

```
Object[] messageArguments = {
    "Mars",
    new Integer(7),
    new Date()
};
```

You call the formatter it this way:

```
MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat("");
formatter.setLocale(currentLocale);
formatter.applyPattern(messages.getString("template"));
String output = formatter.format(messageArguments);
```

the detailed example is here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageFormat.html